# Hyperledger fabric Membership service providers

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Is it possible for the hyperledger fabric executing transactions  without a membership service provider?

Comment: Please know how to ask a question StackOverflow, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Try to brief your question with some information else we will remove or give downvotes. A warning !!

Answer (score 0):

No, its not possible. MSP is used to sign and authorise transactions. for better understanding you should refer https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/msp.html